# Set value of column based on value of choice column - SP Modern List

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, power-automate, conditional, auto-populate

I have a list in which the Project Manager column (text) needs to auto-populate based on the Project Name (choice) column.  Essentially there are a small group of project managers, each assigned to a group of Project Names.  When the user opens the form and selects a Project Name from the drop down list, I want the Project Manager field to auto-populate.  I'm just not sure what the best route is here.  Would Power Automate be an option?  The column conditional formatting seems to only give me the option of selecting a color if a column has specific values.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: How many project names (choices) are their? If you have fixed small group of project managers then you can "show" them in list view using column formatting as well. If you want to store the managers names values in a column & use it anywhere else, power apps form customization or updating column name after item submit using power automate will also work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for cascading lists where the choice in one choice column changes the selection in a different column.

Using a combination of a lists, JSON column formatting and Power Apps forms customization.  Microsoft has a nice tutorial here:  [Working with Cascading Lists in SharePoint and Power Apps](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/community/working-with-cascading-lists-in-sharepoint-and-powerapps)

Essentially you create a series of lists with a mapping relationship between the choices, then customize your form using Power Apps to set a filter on the form fields using previous columns value as the filter key.  The filter pulls in items from a list with the proper mapped values to display as choices.  JSON column formatting makes it all look nice.

You can find additional column formatting samples here: [pnp List-Formatting](https://github.com/pnp/List-Formatting)

Answer (score 1):

A good solution would be to have another list to store your projects and project managers. Then in your target list, you would create a lookup column to your project list (project name column) and include the project manager as additional information to be shown in your target list. More information can be found here:

[Create list relationships by using lookup columns](https://support.microsoft.com/office/create-list-relationships-by-using-lookup-columns-80a3e0a6-8016-41fb-ad09-8bf16d490632)